# AS3 beginners: How to put these simple codes together?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to AS3 and I need some help putting something with the FLVPlayBack component together.

**When I put this in the first frame of my timeline:**

```
player.volume = 0;
player._uiMgr._isMuted = true;
```

I get an error:

> > **Error** Scene=3A - Intro, layer=Actions, frame=1:Line 27: The member is private and cannot be accessed.
> >     videoplayer._uiMgr._isMuted = true;

Someone said "create a setter method to do it and the compiler error should disappear!"

But even after googling setter methods, I have no idea how to resolve this issue.

Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: What is the type (class) of player? Is it a class you downloaded from somwhere? Is it a class from flash or flex?

Comment: Oh there's no class yet. Do I need to create an .as file for this? I can name it anything then in that case. Would you be able to show me how the package script should be for this to work?

Comment: @AndreyKo, the codes are in the first frame of my timeline atm.

Comment: Oh, I meant what is this "player" you are referring to. Anyway, I think this is what you are looking for: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-193603.html

Comment: Hi Andrey, thank you so much but I have looked at that thread already, but unfortunately I don't know how any of the solutions work. I'm such a newbie - but I'm trying hard to learn! Would you be able to kindly show me an actual flash file?

Comment: Sorry, I have no flash where I am now, but if you are just starting with it - you don't have to create external .as files. Write code wherever it was, that you wrote the code above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that _uiMgr and _isMuted are `private attributes` (hence the _). Do they have getters assigned to them? If they do you should be able to use `player.uiMgr.isMuted = true;`

EDIT: You have to assign a muteButton to FLVPlayer and then dispatch clickevent on it. Like this http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?193603-FLVPlayback-actionscript-Mute&p=2412841&viewfull=1#post2412841

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for your comment. I've put these into the first frame of my main timeline `player.volume = 0; player.uiMgr.isMuted = true;`, but it's giving me errors. "1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property uiMgr through a reference with static type fl.video:FLVPlayback."

Comment: This is because FLVPlayback does have a getter/public attribute called uiMgr. See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

Comment: I have never used FLVPlayback but if you want to mute it, it seems that you have to dispatch a clickevent on a button that you use for mute. I will update my asnwer.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you again and I understand the logic of what you're saying...But unfortunately I don't know how to turn this into codes...I am a newbie but I am trying my best to learn atm... is it a class file I have to put together? Would you be able to kindly show me the actual codes to how the package should look like?

Comment: I dont have much - I have 2 layers, one with a FLVplayback component with an instance name of 'player', it has a video link and the autoPlay set to yes. Another layer for scripts and in the first frame, I have `player.volume = 0;player.uiMgr.isMuted = true;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3263/discussion-between-rob-fox-and-muudles)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable "player", you want to work with, here is what you should do.

(1) First determine the type of the variable: Run:

```
  trace( typeof player );
```

In your case, it would output "FLVPlayback"

(2) Now go to flash reference on Adobe's site, and look for that class:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html

(3) In the reference you can find the following:
  (a) Public properties: These are the class variables you may set values to. There are some more variables in this class, that are not listed here, as you have no access to them - because they are not public - they exist only for classes (or package) internal usage. (Example: _uiMgr)

(b) Public methods - these are functions you may run. Here also there are more functions, that are for internal use and not listed.

(c) Events - very important part of AS3. Used for sending messages, or trigerring behaviour between different classes, and for interaction with the user. Read this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html

(d) Public Constants

Now, In your case, looks like you are trying to mute the player.
Looking for "mute" in the above list, will give you only one result:
  muteButton : Sprite Mute button control.
  We would expect something better, but we will have to work with that. This is a button, and we will make flash think that a user clicked on it - and mute.
The following line will do the trick:

```
 player.muteButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

P.S.

When a variable is defined this way:`Object player = new FLVPlayback();`, running `trace(typeof player)` will return "Object". You will need to run `trace(player.constructor)` to see the runtime type of the variable.

Comment: Hi Andrey...I think you will want to kill me...I ran the trace and it came up as 'object'. when I put `player.muteButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK)); ` in, it gives me an error saying "#1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." Did it work when you tested it? Would it be possible for me to download your file?

Comment: Did you put the code into the first frame of your main timeline? Because in another comment flash recognised the "player" as "FLVPlayback". + (I didn't test it...)

Comment: Well, I didn't work with FLVPlayback... Maybe your player has no mute button, and there is a way to add one in the GUI.